# Python tkinter. Как проверить какое поле ввода активно

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, focus

Есть у меня калькулятор с двумя полями ввода. Ввод осуществляется при помощи кнопок приложения. Нужно чтобы, при нажатии на кнопку клавиатуры приложения, проверялась какое из полей активно, и в него записывался символ.

Проблема в проверке активности поля ввода. Не могу найти удобный метод.

Есть widget.focus_get(), но он выводит идентификационный номер, типа .54217845.645673123, который разный при каждом запуске. В boolean его, естественно, не переведешь, он либо True либо None.

Есть еще bind, но он осуществляет привязку только к клавиатуре и мыши.

Comment: А зачем проверять какое из полей активно?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev  Чтобы знать куда записывать цифры через entry_widg.insert("insert", n).

Comment: Но ведь цифры и так записываются в то поле, на котором фокус. Зачем выполнять для этого дополнительные действия?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Это если вводить с клавиатуры, а у меня ввод с кнопок приложения.

Comment: Т.е. смотри, я создаю 10 кнопок соответствующих всем цифрам. И к каждому привязываю команду для записи ств цифры. Но в какой из полей ввода записывать, это ведь надо указывать.

Comment: Теперь понял. Могу ошибаться, но в момент нажатия на кнопку, поле ввода потеряет фокус, а получит его нажимаемая кнопка.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Действительно.
Но вот в чем дело, если вывести номер, который возвращает foocus_get() и проверить его на равенство с текущим фокусом вот так
```
def kboard_cmnd(n):

    if ".!frame.!entry" == str(root.focus_get()):
        numb_ent = numb1_ent
    elif ".!frame.!entry2" == str(root.focus_get()):
        numb_ent = numb2_ent
    
    numb_ent.insert("insert", n)
```
то все работает как надо. Пока ты не запустил программу на другом устройстве.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно запоминать в каком поле фокус был в последний раз:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
current_entry = None

def on_focus(evt):
    global current_entry
    current_entry = evt.widget


def on_click():
    if current_entry is not None:
        current_entry.insert('insert', 'Hello')


e1 = Entry(root)
e1.bind('<FocusIn>', on_focus)
e1.pack()

e2 = Entry(root)
e2.bind('<FocusIn>', on_focus)
e2.pack()

button = Button(root, text='Click me', command=on_click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Да, то что надо! Спасибо большое.